# How to change time format of a RSS feed in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using a 'view' to display a set of rss feeds(Specifically a list of events imported from a calendar). On each of these feeds the date is shown in the format of:

> **Tuesday, November 28, 2014**

But I would like to get it in the form of:

> **Nov 28**

Is there any way I can get this done? Maybe with some JS?

Comment: Per SO's [quality question guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), can you show what code you have already attempted?  That will allow us to better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different steps needs to be done to achieve this.

1. Create a custom date format
2. Create a new date type and assign the custom created date format
3. Activate the RSS display of your content type
4. Change the display of your date field by using the newly created date type

**Create a custom date format**

You can do this under `Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Date and time`, the `Formats` tab. Click on `Add format` and put `M j` as format string. This will create a date format under the form of `Nov 28`.

**Create new date type**

Under the tab `Types` (also under `Administration » Configuration » Regional and language`), create a new type and assign your custom date format as format.

**Activate RSS display of your content type**

Next thing is to activate a custom display used by RSS view mode, go to the `manage display` settings of your content type. For example for the `Basic page` content type, it is under `Administration » Structure » Content types » Basic page`. Click on the `CUSTOM DISPLAY SETTINGS` collapsible fieldset and activate the `RSS` checkbox. This will add a new tab `RSS` above on the right.

**Change display for RSS**

Still under the same manage display screen, click on the RSS tab. Next to your date field, click the `Settings` icon to change output. In the dropdown, choose your newly created date type.

Comment: This is the correct approach when modifying the default RSS feed or a Views-based feed using the full node view. For a field-based RSS view, you can set the format in the Views field configuration based on regional settings or a format specific to that Views field.

Comment: This is not working for me, although I understand all the steps described here. I can customize the default's and teaser's settings, but the RSS changes don't seem to affect it. --- I also cleared caches and ran Cron. Is this perhaps because I don't have the **Views**-module installed?

Comment: No, you don't need to use Views module. You activated the RSS display mode on your content type ?